# Can't open subwindow created by glade

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I am a beginner at Glade 
Here is my code. I don't know why aboutdialog run but addwindow not.
When add button pressed addwindow will be show.
How can i tell glade which object i want signal handler connect to?

Thank for advice

```
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
typedef struct 
{



  GtkWidget *imagemenuitem1;
  GtkWidget *imagemenuitem5;
  GtkWidget *aboutdialog;
  GtkWidget *add;
  GtkWidget *addwindow;
 }Data;

void open_add_window( GtkWidget *widget, Data *  data) 
{
  gtk_widget_show (data->addwindow );  
  gtk_widget_hide (data->addwindow);
}

    void quit_main_window(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}

void open_about_window(GtkWidget *widget, Data *data)
{

 gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(data->aboutdialog));
gtk_widget_hide(data->aboutdialog);
}
int
main( int    argc,
    char **argv )
{
  GtkBuilder *builder;
 GtkWidget  *window;
 Data data;
  GError     *error = NULL;
/* Init GTK+ */
gtk_init( &argc, &argv );

/* Create new GtkBuilder object */
builder = gtk_builder_new();
/* Load UI from file. If error occurs, report it and quit application.
 * Replace "tut.glade" with your saved project. */
if( ! gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, "2.glade", &error ) )
{
    g_warning( "%s", error->message );
    g_free( error );
    return( 1 );
}

/* Get main window pointer from UI */
window = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "window" ) );
data.imagemenuitem1 = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder,"imagemenuitem1") );
data.imagemenuitem5 = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder,"imagemenuitem5") );
data.aboutdialog = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "aboutdialog"));
data.add = GTK_WIDGET ( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "add"));
data.addwindow = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "addwindow"));

/* Connect signals */
gtk_builder_connect_signals( builder, &data );


/* Destroy builder, since we don't need it anymore */
g_object_unref( G_OBJECT( builder ) );

/* Show window. All other widgets are automatically shown by GtkBuilder */
gtk_widget_show( window );

/* Start main loop */
gtk_main();

return( 0 );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer:*** I use [**gtkmm**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/) with C++ so I'm not sure how this works out in plain vanilla C - you didn't tag your post with respect to what language and GTK tools you're using, but it appears that you are using C, not C++ , so I don't think you have the gtkmm signal handling mechanism available - if so this answer won't be of much help, although you can probably do something similar in C:

I never use `gtk_builder_connect_signals()`. You can (should?) connect signals explicitly by grabbing the widget you want using `GtkBuilder::get_widget()`, like this:

```
Widget* w;
Builder->get_widget( widgetName, w );
```

This means that you don't set up the signals and handlers in Glade, you do it in your code - more work, but better control and clarity.

Once you get the widget by name, you can use `static_cast<T&>()` to get a reference to the exact widget type that your widget actually is. This is necessary because each specific widget type has its own signals, so you need to get the specific widget type. For example:

```
Button& button1 = static_cast < Button& > ( *w );
```

Then, connect the widget you've grabbed explicitly to the desired signal handler - here is an example from [**Gnone Developer's Guide: Connecting signal handlers**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-connecting-signal-handlers.html.en)

```
#include <gtkmm/button.h>

void on_button_clicked()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}

main()
{
    Gtk::Button button("Hello World");
    button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&on_button_clicked));
}
```

The key call is **button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&on_button_clicked));** - where you specify exactly what widget you are connecting: **button**; what signal you are grabbing: **signal_clicked**; what function you want to be called for that signal: **on_button_clicked**.

Consult the developers guide above for more ways of using `widget.connect()` - there are several overloads and variations for self standing signal handlers, member function signal handlers, and passing arguments into the signal handler when it's called.